Building a time stack chart in AnyLogic
I am a new user to AnyLogic. I'm trying to create a chart which can capture agents at a specific time, let's say, count the agent every 60 mins and can show number of agents with their status.
I try Time Stack Chart and the result shown as figure1 but my expected chart is figure2 and It should be update continuously.
Please, is it possible to do the chart like this?
Thank you everyone in advance
[edit] My setup for the chart is figure3 I count agents at the time when they leave the Delay block figure4 and the agent's colour refers to the agent state chart figure5
Thank you.

you probably setup the TimeStackChart wrongly, always share your setup so we can help.  Or to answer your question: Yes, it is possible to do a chart like figure 2...

PS: Only use the "anylogic" tag, that suffices :)

Hello Benjamin, I put more details for everyone to understand the problems better. Thank you so much :))

To achieve figure 2, use several "Stack chart"s, 1 for each hour, next to each other... But it is up to you to "feed" the right chart for the right hour with the right data for that hour.
(what you want is not what a "time stack chart" is for).

Thank you Benjamin, this solution works on my model
